# How do I run a Powershell script from PHP

Tags: php, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I wrote one line of powershell script that downloads DHCP lease data. when i run it from powershell it works (exports the data into a csv file). but if i run the same code from php it exports an empty csv file. The powershell script and php code id below.

```
DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "HAP2000-11" -ScopeId 10.10.10.0 | Select-Object -Property IPAddress, Clientid, Description, HostName | Export-Csv -Path ("C:\wamp64\www\new.csv")
```

php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['updateDHCP'])){
        shell_exec('powershell.exe -command C:\wamp64\www\DhcpLeasesExport1.ps1');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does the user running PHP has the appropriate permissions to read those DHCP data?

Comment: How do you give such permissions @TobyU

Comment: You will find a local security group named "DHCP Users" on your Windows based DHCP server. Add your PHP user into that group to give read permissions on your DHCP server.

Comment: is there any other way round this. other than adding the PHP to the DHCP server @TobyU

Comment: Maybe. Talk to your DHCP administrator.